# Vue Static images not working when deployed on web server

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have created a Vue-cli project and it working fine on my local server. And when I 'npm run build' and deployed it to my web server I see my static-images and icon-fonts not working.

My App link : http://www.bootstrapdash.com/demo/star-admin-pro-vue/

Comment: Look the console they all have error 404 : not found

Comment: Files are there in the static directory, but the issue is with path when a build was taken !!